# jQuery animate to bottom after timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

The situation is as follows:

When the user clicks on a specific link (within div.Foo), a page is loaded. 
What I want is the "scroll to bottom" is carried out only after the user has clicked and the new page is loaded (and not at the same time).

So far I have the following piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.Foo a').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
    }, 100);
  });

});
```

But it's not working correctly.

Note!: I can not use preventDefault because the new page should be loaded! And also use of #hash is not possible because the URLs are dynamically generated.

Comment: have you try to add `preventDefault` to the handler?

Comment: It's working for me in chrome. you have a syntax error, missing a } before the last );

Comment: a preventdefault will stop the new page from loading. If it's a regular link, the above wont work, since the page with the javascript has been unloaded when the new page is loaded. You'll have to do it without the click function on the new page.

Comment: Do you need to scroll bottom on the new page?

Comment: @Frogmouth Yes indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scroll Bottom on docReady

You can add an `hashtag` to your `Foo a` url like:

`[yourlink]#scrollBottom`

`<div class="Foo"><a href="http://test/#scrollBottom">Click Me</a></div>`

and in the first page not add any JS, in the destination page add this code:

```
$(function(){
    if(location.hash.indexOf("scrollBottom") >= 0) 
     $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({ scrollTop: $("body").height() }, 'slow');
})
```

with this, if there is an hashtag `#scrollBottom` in the URL, page scrolls to bottom after 1 second (one second to show you the delay, set what you like).

---

### add Hashtah dynamically on click

You can add `#hashtag` dynamically when someone click `Foo a` edit your handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.Foo a').click(function (e) {
      e.prevemtDefault();
      location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "#scrollBottom";
  });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.Foo a').click(function () {
      $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "#scrollBottom");
  });
});
```

`#scrollBottom`  is just an example, you can use one whatsoever.

:) try...

Comment: This is not possible because the URLs are dynamically generated. So I can not apply #hash in my urls.

Comment: Ohh... you can via Javascript. I edit my answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

After the click of the anchor has occured, it loads a new page, so your other JavaScript won't be executed. You have to add the JavaScript on the new page to scroll to the part you want.

Comment: The preventDefault is stopping the new page from loading and this is not the solution. So it SHOULD load the new page and then animate to the bottom.

Comment: I see, so a new page is loaded? Then the JavaScript after it won't be executed. You have to set the JavaScript on the new loaded page.

Comment: yes but the problem is, the main script is loaded on all pages. And the different pages are actually product variants.